# Retry in case of Data Loss in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy for web scraping, but getting data loss warning for few requests, each time I run the same spider, it gives me these data loss error on different urls, so I believe that it just needs to retry for these requests, does anyone know, how can I do that?
I am getting following warning few times:

```
 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11] WARNING: Got data loss in <failed link>  If you want to process broken responses set the setting DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False -- This message won't be shown in further requests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message says you will need to configure Scrapy to handle failed downloads. The reference for configuring Scrapy is a great resource to do so depending on how you decide to run or configure your program.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

As long as the servers are not misconfigured and these are temporary issues you can set the `RETRY_ENABLED` flag to `True` and the `DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS` flag to False in order to retry failed scrapes.

Comment: The docs seem to suggest the `DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS` flat should be set to `True` - "If RETRY_ENABLED is True and this setting is set to True, the ResponseFailed([_DataLoss]) failure will be retried as usual." - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-fail-on-dataloss

Comment: However the actual generated error message seems to say the opposite: `If you want to process broken responses set the setting DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False`. In my case it doesn't look like the URL with the broken response was retried so I think the answer above is correct!

Comment: that's true, `DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATA_LOSS = FALSE` means the engine will still parse the data even when there is missing chunk, So for example if you're expecting a json result you won't be able to parse it without the missing chunk, be careful with this one, i think it is better to go for a custom retry middleware.